# Mongoose shorten time caused by "findById" and ".save"

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, base64, compression

I have this method to edit my items in my mongodb atlas database:

```
router.post("/edit", upload.single("image"), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("edit call: " + Date.now());


    Schema.findById(req.body.editId, function (err, doc) {

        if (err) {
            console.error('error, no entry found');
        }

        if (req.file.path) {
            console.log("before buffer create: " + Date.now());
            doc.image = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync(req.file.path)).toString("base64");
            console.log("after buffer create: " + Date.now());
        }
        
        doc.save((err) => {
                console.log("saved: " + Date.now());
                res.redirect('/admin');
            }
        );
    })


});
```

---

Output: (only 1 document in database)

```
edit call:            1622842404818
before buffer create: 1622842405819
after buffer create:  1622842405822
saved:                1622842406382
```

So my conclusion is:

- findById takes 1 second
- saving takes 500ms (I've already seen up to 1500ms)

---

Now I wanna ask if there's any way to reduce this time. I'm feared of the time it will take if there are way more items in the database.

Is saving time dependant on base64 string length (some pictures produce 700k characters strings)?

Comment: Try using MongoDB's database profiling to get more detail about what it is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the good practice would be to store your images in some storage and to put the URL of that image to MongoDB, and not to put the actual image in MongoDB.

But if you want to proceed with this approach, you can update the document in one call with `findByIdAndUpdate`, instead of fetching the document with `findById` and saving it with `save()`.

```
router.post("/edit", upload.single("image"), async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await Schema.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.editId, {
      image = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync(req.file.path)).toString("base64")
    });
    console.log("saved: " + Date.now());
    res.redirect('/admin');
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ success: false, error })
  }
});
```